# Why does iScroll is bouncing back to initial position?

Tags: iscroll4

I am using iscroll and it works well until one point but at some point the scrolling area is bouncing back.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var gridScroll = new iScroll('iscroll-wrapper-grid');
  }, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hjakw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ul {
    margin:0;
}

Fixes the problem.  Not sure why iscroll doesn't take margin into account.  Maybe it says something in the docs about that.